# Can my son play Minecraft with his Xbox 360 friends if he has Xbox one?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console

My son asked for an Xbox one and Minecraft for Christmas, but now he found out that his friends will be playing the game on Xbox 360. Will he be able to play with them? Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the Microsoft support [site](http://support.xbox.com/en-CA/xbox-360/games/minecraft-version-differences) you can't.

> Minecraft: Xbox 360 Edition can only be played with other Xbox 360 consoles on Xbox Live, and the Xbox One edition can only be played online with other Xbox One consoles. There is no cross-platform play with the other editions of Minecraft.

Comment: I was afraid of that. We've already purchased the Xbox one for him. Thanks for your fast response.

Comment: @RaineeRose I'm sorry to hear your situation.  However, Xbox 360's can go for very cheap if you manage to find the right one without a large HDD.  A refurbished (used, but repaired and inspected) xbox 360 sells for $99 at gamestop.  You can probably find someone selling it as low as $50 on ebay.  Minecraft has a relatively small size (I think less than 100 MB), so you don't need a fancy new one.  I don't know your financial situation, but this is your best bet if he REALLY wants to play Minecraft on the 360

Comment: FWIW, cross-platform multiplayer is extremely rare to non-existent in on consoles.